# Which manga chapter correspond to the end of episode 12 of season 2 of the anime?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Can anyone tell me which chapter in the manga is the end of episode 12 from the second season of *Seven Deadly Sins*?

Comment: Related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/48672/which-the-seven-deadly-sins-manga-chapters-correspond-to-the-2nd-season-of-the

Answer (score 1):

The **Seven Deadly Sins: Revival of The Commandments** episode 12 covers chapters 136, 137, 141, 142 and 143 (source: [Wiki](http://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_12)), so the end of episode 12 should be chapter 143.

In case you're asking because you want to continue reading the manga where the anime left off start from chapter 143, as part of it will be covered by [episode 13](http://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_13), and read chapter 138 first for the same reason.

By the way you can find a chapter to episode comparison broken down by arcs [here](http://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Story_Arcs).