# Which manga chapters correspond to the 2nd season (or "Season 3" on Netflix) of the anime, "Revival of the Commandments"?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

The 2nd season (labeled as "Season 3" on Netflix) of the anime, *Nanatsu no Taizai: Imashime no Fukkatsu* (or *The Seven Deadly Sins: Revival of The Commandments*), has ended.

Which manga chapters correspond to each of the anime episodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The Seven Deadly Sins: Revival of The Commandments* covers **chapter 102 (volume 13) up to chapter 197 (volume 24) + 2 extras (volume 26).**

- **Post-Kingdom Infiltration arc**

  1. [Revival of the Demon Clan](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_1): chapters 102-107, 109
  2. [Existence and Proof](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_2): chapters 104-105, 108-112
- **Albion arc**

  3. [Sacred Treasure Lostvayne](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_3): chapters 113-116
  4. [The Ten Commandments on the Move](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_4): chapters 117-119
  5. [Overwhelming Violence](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_5): chapters 120-122, 139
- **Istar arc**

  6. [The Great Holy Knight Atones for His Sins](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_6): chapters 123-125
  7. [Where Memories Lead](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_7): chapters 126, side story 3 (volume 16)
  8. [The Druids' Holy Land](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_8): chapters 127-130
  9. [A Promise to a Loved One](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_9): chapters 130-131
- **Ravens arc**

  9. [A Promise to a Loved One](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_9): chapters 138-139
  10. [What We Lacked](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_10): chapters 132-133, 140
  11. [Father and Son](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_11): chapters 134-135, 140-141
  12. [Where Love is Found](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_12): chapters 136-137, 141-143
  13. [Farewell, Beloved Thief](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_13): chapters 138, 143-146
  14. [Master of the Sun](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_14): chapters 147-150
- **Great Fight Festival arc**

  15. [A Bloodcurdling Confession](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_15): chapters 151-154
  16. [Death-Trap Maze](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_16): chapters 155-160
  17. [Legendary Figures](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_17): chapters 160-165
  18. [For Whom Does That Light Shine?](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_18): chapters 166-170
  19. [Meliodas vs. The Ten Commandments](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_19): chapters 171-175
  20. [Have Hope](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_20): chapters 176-177
- **Defensive Battle for Liones arc**

  20. [Have Hope](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_20): chapters 178-179
  21. [Certain Warmth](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_21): chapters 180-183
  22. [Return of the Sins](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_22): chapters 184-188
  23. [The Hero Rises!!](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_23): chapters 189-194
  24. [So Long as You're Here](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_24): chapters 195-197 (volume 24), extras 11-12 (volume 26)

---

Source: [Nanatsu no Taizai Wikia - Episode Guide, Season 2](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_Guide#Season_2)